# Прелоад целого сайта

Tags: ajax, javascript

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы сайт сначала загрузился и после вывелся на экран. Без flash, на JS. Вот примерно _http://playdulla.com/ так либо просто с круглым gif файлом при заргузке сайта

Comment: вопрос а нафига если это не Flash?

Прелоад нужен только для флешек, когда htm сайт начинает грузиться и показывать прелоад - я его закрываю и никогда не возвращусь на него пока не уберут эту фигню.

Comment: Повеселить посетителей))) правда не долго XD)

З.Ы. Меня поражает, как сделать так как на этом сайте? ППЦ... Ну там же сделано както, копайтесь в их скриптах на здоровье...

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showSite() {
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.height='100%';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.overflow='show';
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';
  }
</script>

<body onload="showSite()">
<div id="loading" style="text-align: center">
  загрузка...
</div>
<div id="wrapper" style="height:1px;overflow: hidden;">
 <!-- сайт -->
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно на вашем примере использовано это - [QueryLoader](http://blog.g63.ru/jquery/queryloader-предзагрузка-страницы-на-jquery/), что видно в исходном коде.

Comment: > что видно в исходном коде
Что ТС и должен был сделать прежде чем задавать вопрос)